# Get Specific Type of JComponent

Tags: java, swing, jcomponent, instanceof

I am using a JComponent array variable to hold both JTextField and JComboBox components. Is there a built in way to check the type of a JComponent for use in a conditional statement? I can't seem to find a suitable method in the API.

Comment: `if (comp instanceof JTextField) etc...`

Comment: Ah of course, thanks that should do the trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a language feature rather than an API thing.

If you want to check whether `blah` is an instance of `SomeClass`, you just write

```
if (blah instanceof SomeClass) {
    //do stuff
}
```

Normally you will then want to treat it as being of that class, so you'll cast it:

```
if (blah instanceof SomeClass) {
    SomeClass someBlah = (SomeClass) blah;
    //do stuff
}
```

You know that the cast can't fail because you checked with `instanceof`.

Note that this is not checking *exact* types, but whether `blah` is *compatible* with `SomeClass`; i.e., whether it's `SomeClass` or a subclass of `SomeClass`.

It should also be said that most people don't care much for `instanceof`, and see it as something that should be used sparingly. It usually turns up as a side effect of a bad design. (But not *always*, say I.)

Comment: Thanks, @splungebob's comment was all I needed, but I'll mark this as correct for anyone who needs the information in the future as it's the same answer.